# How to generate function arguments as a sequence with length specified in a template argument

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing, clang++

What's a clean way to generalise a template to pass a variable number of arguments (the count given as a template argument) to a function?  For example the function `permute`, below:

```
template<std::size_t N>
using byte_vector_t = uint8_t __attribute__((ext_vector_type(N)));

template <std::size_t N, int(*f)(int)>
byte_vector_t<N> permute(byte_vector_t<N> x, byte_vector_t<N> y) {
    return __builtin_shufflevector(x, y, f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4), f(5), f(6), f(7), f(8), f(9), f(10), f(11), f(12), f(13), f(14), f(15) );
}

template <std::size_t N>
byte_vector_t<N> zip_lo(byte_vector_t<N> x, byte_vector_t<N> y) {
    auto f = [](int i) -> int { return ((i & 1) ? N : 0) + (i / 2); };
    return permute<N, f>(x, y);
}
```

But that only works for N=16:

```
// works
typedef uint8_t test16_t __attribute__((ext_vector_type(16)));
test16_t zip_lo16(test16_t x, test16_t y) {
    return zip_lo(x, y);
}

// does not work    
typedef uint8_t test8_t __attribute__((ext_vector_type(8)));
test8_t zip_lo8(test8_t& x, test8_t& y) {
    return zip_lo(x, y);
}
```

`std::apply` seemed like it might be relevant, but `__builtin_shufflevector` refused be passed into that.  Even if it worked I still wouldn't know how best to generate the tuple.

Comment: [OT]: prefer to place deducing parameters after non-deducing ones, so you might write `permute<f>(x, y)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point. I updated the answer to reflect that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do with with an [`index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence):

```cpp
#include <utility>

template <int (*f)(int), std::size_t N>
byte_vector_t<N> permute(byte_vector_t<N> x, byte_vector_t<N> y) {
    return [&]<std::size_t... I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        return __builtin_shufflevector(x, y, f(I)...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

template <std::size_t N>
byte_vector_t<N> zip_lo(byte_vector_t<N> x, byte_vector_t<N> y) {
    auto f = [](int i) -> int { return ((i & 1) ? N : 0) + (i / 2); };
    return permute<f>(x, y);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Kbz6r36Ka)

---

If you use C++17, you can't use generic lambdas so you'd need a helper function:

```cpp
template <int (*f)(int), std::size_t... I>
byte_vector_t<sizeof...(I)> permute_helper(byte_vector_t<sizeof...(I)> x,
                                           byte_vector_t<sizeof...(I)> y,
                                           std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    return __builtin_shufflevector(x, y, f(I)...);
}

template <std::size_t N, int (*f)(int)>
byte_vector_t<N> permute(byte_vector_t<N> x, byte_vector_t<N> y) {
    return permute_helper<f>(x, y, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Note: You may want to consider taking the `byte_vector`s by reference instead.

Comment: Worse than C++17, actually.  I'm on C++11.  But maybe I can make up the difference with Abseil.

Comment: @sh1 C++11 doesn't support the kind of template parameters you use though. Your question only makes sense from C++17 and onwards.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I forgot to set `-std=c++11` when I started trying to figure it out in godbolt.  The project I'm working on is c++11, but with comments promising to move to a later version imminently.

Comment: @sh1 I'm not understanding what you're saying right now. Your template use is not supported in C++11. It's supported from C++17 and forward. I'll be happy to try answer a proper question.